# How do I delete or modify on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, edits

I want to rectify a question on this website, but I didn't get the link how to modify my question. Do I need to delete that question and again ask like a new question or I can modify my question?

Comment: You could have commented on the question you posted earlier, there was no need to open up a new question. The answer to your question: There is an edit button just below the question. First button is share and second is edit and should be in grey text.

Comment: i was not able to delete as it says that you can't delete this question as other had invest their time on it that was i asked is that any other way to delete it.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

You have edit and delete option below your question, or you also comment below question to notify update.

Comment: Noteworthy that doing so also bumps the question at top of the _active questions_ tab.

Comment: +0.5: they're called free hand *circles* for a reason.